# Why is my method for finding all divisors for two numbers isn't working

Tags: c++, for-loop, numbers, number-formatting

So I made a while loop for finding all divisors for given numbers and it's the following

```
int a,b;
int temp =0;
cout << "Enter the first number : ";
cin  >> a;
cout << "Enter the second number : ";
cin >> b;
int smallestNum = a<b?a:b;
while(true)
    {
        temp++;
        if(a%temp == 0 && b%temp == 0) cout << temp << ", ";
        if (temp == smallestNum) break;
    }
    cout << "are all the divisors for both numbers";
```

and it worked like expected but when i tried to do the same in a for loop it didn't go as planned

```
int a,b;
int temp;
cout << "Enter the first number : ";
cin  >> a;
cout << "Enter the second number : ";
cin  >> b;
temp = a<b?a:b;
for (int i; i == temp; i++)
{
    if(a%i==0 && b%i==0) cout << i << ", ";
}
cout << "are all the divisors for both numbers";
```

I can't even find the problem in my code to fix it, how can I fix it????

Comment: `int i;` hasn't been initialized.  Hilarity and hijinks ensue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` loop will iterate as long as condition is `true`, your condition is `i == temp` which is (in general) `false`, you should change it to `i != temp`

Comment: I completely blanked on that when copying the code from a while loop to a for loop, thanks a lot